# When does $X_k\to\ N(\mu_1,\sigma^{2}_1)$ and $Y_k\to\ N(\mu_2,\sigma^{2}_2)$ imply $X_k+Y_k$ also converges to Normal Distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $\{X_1, X_2, …\}$ and $\{Y_1, Y_2, …\}$ be sequences of i.i.d. random variables (however, $X_i$s are not independent of $Y_i$s). Suppose that $X_k\ {\xrightarrow {d}}\ N\left(\mu_1,\sigma^{2}_1\right)$ and $Y_k\ {\xrightarrow {d}}\ N\left(\mu_2,\sigma^{2}_2\right)$

The question is, under which conditions we have that the sum $X_k+Y_k$ also converges to the normal distribution?

Comment: I think the $X_i$ being subindependent of the $Y_i$ would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(X_n,Y_n)$ are **jointly** normal such that $(X_n,Y_n) \rightarrow (X,Y)$ where $X \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_
2^2)$, then $X_k + Y_k \xrightarrow{D} X + Y$. This is a consequence of the [Continuous Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Statement), applied to the function $g(x,y) = x + y$.